# How do I declare multiple mutable variables at the same time?

Tags: rust

I can declare multiple constants like this:

```
let (a, b, c) = (1, 0.0, 3);
```

But why can't I do this with mutable variables?

`let mut (a, b, c) = (1, 0.0, 3);` throws a compile error:

```
error: expected identifier, found `(`
 --> <anon>:2:13
2 |>     let mut (a, b, c) = (1, 0.0, 3);
  |>             ^
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The proper syntax is

```
let (mut a, mut b, mut c) = (1, 0.0, 3);
```

Mutability is a property of the binding, and `a`, `b`, and `c` are all different bindings, each bound to a specific element of the tuple after the pattern has been matched. Thus they can be individually made mutable.

If you wanted to specify the type, you could do that too:

```
let (mut a, mut b, mut c): (u8, f32, i32) = (1, 0.0, 3);
```

For numeric literals, you could also use the suffix form:

```
let (mut a, mut b, mut c) = (1u8, 0.0f32, 3i32);
```

Of course, there's no reason to do this for the example code; it's much simpler to just have 3 separate statements.

> declare multiple constants

These aren't constants, they are just immutable variables. A `const` is a different concept.